# Why does Json's Stringify output print differently from console.log output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stringify

For the below code:

```
const testStringify = () => {
        try{
            console.log('Inside testStringify');
            const a = "";
            a.b.c;
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('Inside catch of testStringify');
            console.log(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    
    testStringify();
```

The output is:

```
Inside testStringify
Inside catch of testStringify
Error: {}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
    at testStringify
    at Object.<anonymous>
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Why does Json.stringify(err) (Error: {}) not print output in the same way or in some meaningful way as console.log(err)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` iterates only over own and enumerable properties.

```js
const obj = Object.create({ onProto: 'onProto' });
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'notEnumerable', { value: 'notEnumerable' });
obj.ownAndEnumerable = 'ownAndEnumerable';
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

In some browsers, the `.message` property of Error objects is not an own enumerable property, so it doesn't get iterated over.

For example, in Chrome, the property is own but not enumerable:

```js
const e = new Error('msg');
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e, 'message'));
```

`console.log(err)`, on the other hand, will display the *full object* in the interactive console.